# Why enterprise keywords are not shown in search results?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-keywords

SharePoint 2010 enterprise edition --> I **enabled Enterprise Keywords**, and started to add key words to some pages. When i search for those keywords, i do not get anything in the search results. Am i missing something?

Comment: Has a crawl (full or incremental) run since you added those keywords to the page?

Comment: hmm, i checked and you are right! the incremental crawler was stuck for few days, and the Full did not run. I restarted the crawlers, and i will keep you posted if this will solve the issue. I deeply appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full crawl ensures that the changes are consistently applied to the entire index. So make sure you have at least one full crawl followed by the Incremental crawl. You cannot see the keywords in the Search result until they are indexed.